# How to add client side loader for client side code

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, loader

I have 2000 line of JavaScript code. When I run this JavaScript code it will taking long time. Now I want to show loader on page while executing this this JavaScript like ajax loader.
I short I want client side loader for client side code.

```
Server Side code - Ajax Loader
Client side code - ?
```

Can any one tell me how to do this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: client side loader.... what you you mean ???

Comment: you can show the loader and at the end of your functions callback hide it again

Comment: Why not just use the same spinning loader icon you use for ajax?

Comment: are you using update panel for ajax requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All modern browsers can execute 2000 lines of JS file in a breeze. But if at all there is a user-noticeable delay in executing the script, most browser give a modal window asking the user to continue or stop script execution.

Also try to [optimize and minify](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/)  your JS files to get a much more efficient performance.

If the above does not safisfy you, try to do the below:

- HTML: 
  Add the following div to your HTML page:

  ```
  <div id="loadingPanel" class="loading-panel hidden"></div>
  ```
- CSS:

  ```
  .loading-panel {top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;z-index: 100 !important;background: #fff url('../img/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;opacity:.7;filter: alpha(opacity=70);-moz-user-select: none;-webkit-user-select: none;}
  .hidden {visibility: hidden !important;}
  ```
- JS: 
  Before starting to execute the script or a function in the script, do the following:

  ```
  $("#loadingPanel").removeClass("hidden");
  ```

  After the end of the script or function call, do the following:

  ```
  $("#loadingPanel").addClass("hidden");
  ```

*Tip: Try to use your favorite loading.gif*

Comment: Thank you mankum. It is help me lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in several ways, at the top of your javascript code you can dynamically create an image in the element being changes/updated or create an img element on the page.

First Example with Jquery:

```
$('the-element').html("<img src='ajax-loader.gif'>");
```

In this situation the element starts as an ajax loader, then, upon your script updating the element the element would then change. This may work in some scenarios, but not all.

Second Example with Jquery:

```
$('body').append("<img id='loading' src='ajax-loader.gif' style='position:fixed;left:50%;top:50%;'>");
```

In this example you would place this at the top of your javascript code and adjust the style according to the size of your ajax loading image, you would then place this at the bottom of the javascript code

```
$('#loading').hide();
```

or

```
$('#loading').remove();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I +1d the answer above me, as we are giving the same answer basically.